# How do I transclude part of page while maintaining pagename variable?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I currently have a template that includes the magic variable `PAGENAME` and `FULLPAGENAME` which is then applied to a large number of pages with more detailed information on each item. I would like to transclude a part of those pages to another single summary page while maintaining `PAGENAME` of the parent page.

I have tried to use `subst:FULLPAGENAME`, however all that does is display "`template:*Thepage`*" on all instances where the template is called.

I have also tried to use  the `includeonly` tag, but it doesn't seem to want to work very well.

I'm relatively new to mediawiki, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You can have a transclusion change of arbitrary length; the software has no way of figuring out which link in that chain you need the pagename for.